# Why does "going to kip" mean "going to sleep"?

Tags: etymology, british-english

"Night, folks; I'm off to ***[kip](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kip-4)***."

> *noun*
>   <sub>1</sub>*British* a sleep or nap:
>         *I might have a little kip*
>   [*mass noun*] :
>         *he was trying to get some kip*
>
> *verb* ***(kips, kipping, kipped)***
>   [no object] *British*
>       sleep:
>            *he can kip on her sofa*

Oxford Dictionaries has it as:

> mid 18th century (in the sense 'brothel'): perhaps related to Danish kippe 'hovel, tavern'

Any further etymological info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some more detail on [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-kip1.htm).

The Irish usage as brothel is first recorded in Oliver Goldsmith’s *The Vicar of Wakefield*:

> ... to assist at *tattering a kip* as the phrase was, when we had a mind for a frolic.

The phrase *tattering a kip* meaning "wrecking a brothel".

The word then came to be used for lodging-houses and finally to refer to the act of sleeping itself.

In Partridge's *Dictionary of Common Slang* there's also mention of Danish *kippe* and a possible link to Romany *kipsi* 'a basket' and *kitchema* 'an inn' and a possible nautical origin of *kip* meaning 'hammock'.  However, unfortunately I cannot reproduce the complete entry here.

Comment: I cannot speak for Romani, but _kippe_ (as a noun) is beyond vanishingly rare in Danish. It’s a marginally common verb, meaning ‘tilt’ or ‘lop’ (or ‘dip’ as in ‘dipping the flag’), but according to the dictionary, the noun and the verb are unrelated. The noun is allegedly the same as _kipe_ ‘basket for carrying grain’. Supposedly, the shift from ‘basket’ to ‘hovel’ was helped along by Middle Low German _kiffe_ ‘hut’, whence it was used in compounds to refer specifically to a real dive or a brothel, which is when English presumably borrowed (?) it. Quite a shaky etymology overall, I’d say.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am about to write a question asking for the origins of *kip*, I believe it could be a Chinese loanword, may I copy and paste your comment on my question. It will make my case more convincing :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou Go ahead!

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you in Scotland the word kip also means bed. The derogatory phrase "Still in his kip" means still in bed (not still asleep), when the person should have been up and about already.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia suggests that *kip* is derived from [kipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kipper) a smoked herring fish.

> The English philologist and ethnographer Walter William Skeat derives
>   the word from the Old English *kippian*, to spawn. The origin of the
>   word has various parallels, such as Icelandic *kippa* which means "to
>   pull, snatch" and the German word *kippen* which means "to tilt, to
>   incline". Similarly, the English *kipe* denotes a basket used to catch
>   fish. Another theory traces the word *kipper* to **the kip**, or **small beak,
>   that male salmon develop during the breeding season**.

[Salmon *Kype*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon#Life_cycle)

> The salmon spend about one to five years (depending on the species) in
>   the open ocean, where they gradually become sexually mature. The adult
>   salmon then return primarily to their natal streams to spawn. **Atlantic
>   salmon spend between one and four years at sea.** (When a fish returns
>   after just one year's sea feeding, it is called a grilse in Canada,
>   Britain and Ireland.) Prior to spawning, depending on the species,
>   salmon undergo changes. They may grow a hump, develop canine teeth,
>   **develop a kype** (a pronounced curvature of the jaws in male salmon).
>   All will change from the silvery blue of a fresh-run fish from the sea
>   to a darker colour.

Comment: in Dutch a _kip_ is a chicken. (this adds nothing to the actual question, I just thought it funny)

Comment: @kip  So should I call you a *chick* or a *rooster*? :)

Comment: I like the word _kip_ am many things at once.
But if given the choice between the two then I'll choose rooster 9 times outta 10. :) ☺