# Is "kip" Chinese in origin?

Tags: etymology, british-english, loanwords, origin-unknown

While looking up the history of [kip](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/kip),  I realized that the information about its origins is rather scant. The noun and verb *to kip* in BrEng is often said when a person wishes to take a *short sleep* or a ***quick nap***. It's a colloquial expression and sounds very post-war Britain to my ears.  Surprisingly, [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=kip&searchmode=none) completely ignores the word, listing only *kipper*. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kip#Etymology_2) on the other hand comes to the rescue:

> **1760–70**, probably related to Danish *kippe* (“dive, hovel, cheap inn”) and Middle Low German *kiffe* (“hovel”). From the same distant
>   Germanic root as *cove*.
>
> Noun **kip** (plural kips)
>   (informal, chiefly UK) *A place to sleep; a rooming house; a bed*.
>   (informal, chiefly UK) *Sleep, snooze, nap, forty winks, doze*. "I’m
>   just going for my afternoon kip." (informal, chiefly UK) *A very
>   untidy house or room*. (informal, chiefly UK, dated) *A brothel*.

But thanks to a comment left by [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143822/why-does-going-to-kip-mean-going-to-sleep/143871?noredirect=1#comment295666_143871) it seems the connection between *kippe* and *kip* is quite strained.

> ... but kippe (as a noun) is beyond vanishingly rare in Danish. It’s a
>   marginally common verb, meaning ‘tilt’ or ‘lop’ (or ‘dip’ as in
>   ‘dipping the flag’), but according to the dictionary, the noun and the
>   verb are unrelated. The noun is allegedly the same as kipe ‘basket for
>   carrying grain’. Supposedly, the shift from ‘basket’ to ‘hovel’ was
>   helped along by Middle Low German kiffe ‘hut’, whence it was used in
>   compounds to refer specifically to a real dive or a brothel, which is
>   when English presumably borrowed (?) it. Quite a shaky etymology
>   overall, I’d say

So on my trek to find the truth, I came across the *[Chinese-English Dictionary of the vernacular or spoken language of Amoy](http://books.google.it/books?id=Y0VaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA224&dq=dictionary++kip&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Q3d4U8eJIsmr7AbK94HIBA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dictionary%20%20kip&f=false)* by Carstairs Douglas, printed in 1873, London. The language Amoy or otherwise known as  Xiamenese, Xiamen or Hokkien dialect, I believe gives some insight as to how *[kip](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kip#Etymology_2)* was loaned to the British English language to mean a short sleep or nap. It says

> **Kip** [R. hasty; urgent; in extremity].
>    **tioh-kip**, in very great haste; not willing to wait a moment, as in some very urgent matter.
>   **kip-kip**, very swift, like the demon of thunder [...] said also figuratively of anything to be done in great haste.
>    **kip-sio**, a small thin flat-bottomed earthen kettle for warming things quickly.

Could it be that Dutch sailors adopted this expression? I am blissfully unaware of Danish maritime history but I seem to remember reading somewhere that the Dutch traded with the Chinese, was it the 13th century or later? This in turn reminds me of the Italian explorer Marco Polo and his tales in China in [*The Travels of Marco Polo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Travels_of_Marco_Polo) or, in Italian *Il Milione* ("The Million"). But in Italian the letter *K* is a foreign letter and I can think of no Italian words beginning with ch = /k/ which are remotely related to the meaning of haste, urgency or velocity.

- Could ***kip*** therefore be a *Chinese* loanword in the Danish or English language?
- If not, what is the origin of *kip*? Is the Dutch connection as tenuous as suggested by one user?

Comment: I don't speak a word of Hokkien, but I am guessing those entries represent at least two different words. _Kip_ ‘hasty’ most likely corresponds to 急 (_jí_ in Mandarin) ‘hasty, urgent, rash’; _tioh-kip_ to 着急 (_zháojí_) ‘worry, be anxious, overly eager, impetuous’; and _kip-kip_ to 急急 (_jíjí_) ‘very urgent/swift/anxious’. _Kip-sio_, on the other hand, probably contains a completely unrelated _kip_ (possibly 箕 _jī_ ‘winnowing basket’, though I don't know if that originally ended in a _-p_).

Comment: The only contribution I can make is to say that it was used in a hitherto unusual fashion on Radio 4's *Any Questions* on Friday evening. It was claimed by one of the panel that someone had 'out-kipped Ukip'. So watch this space; it may open up a whole new usage of the word 'kip', which could come to mean to behave in an anti-immigrant ethnocentric manner.

Comment: In Cantonese (which I do not speak), 急 is pronounced gàp.  According to Wiktionary, 急急 ‘gàpgàp’ is the source of English ‘chop-chop’ (basically meaning ‘hurry up’.)  If this same character with its Amoy (Taiwanese) pronunciation was also the source of ‘kip’, that would be an interesting coincidence.  It seems unlikely, though.

Comment: The problem with this etymology is that kip just means sleep, not a quick sleep. It's not a very common word these days and sounds a bit dated although it would be understood. Typical usages: _I'm looking for a place to kip._ _How much kip did you get last night?_ _I had a quick kip this afternoon._ I believe it's of Dutch origin.

Comment: I'm sorry but @TheMathemagician you've just contradicted yourself with "I had a quick kip this afternoon" I can assure you that in BrEng *kip* is *also* a **quick nap**, and not only a full night's sleep. I agree that the term sounds dated, I mentioned it in my question too :)

Comment: I am a Brit! I don't think I've contradicted myself ... the presence of _quick_ supports my claim that kip, in itself, doesn't mean a short sleep but more of a casual one, perhaps not in one's normal bed, or after some disturbance from routine. It could equally apply to a particularly long and refreshing sleep.

Comment: Following on my comment above, Hobson-Jobson mentions 'kip-kip' under the entry for 'chop-chop'.  But of course it's not Mandarin, but Hokkien.  Link here:  http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/search3advanced?dbname=hobson&query=kip&matchtype=exact&display=utf8

Comment: @user2619  *kip-kip* definitely has an onomatopoeic quality to it. Thank you for the link. But why hasn't anyone else answered my question? Kip-kip people, what's keeping you? Fuse your comments 2619 into an answer and I'll upvote you :)

Comment: *Kippe* may be "beyond vanishingly rare" in Danish, but then one can buy a *stang* in a Danish bakery and I could guess what they were because I knew *stang* was a vanishingly rare noun in English meaning "stick". Current rarity doesn't rule out something as a cognate.

Comment: It makes me think of how "bungalow" is Indian in origin, from the colonial period.

Comment: I am inclined to the view that the origins of the word are to be found in Britain rather than in China or Denmark.  I believe the OED has sown confusion around this word by it's misleading suggestion that  _'kip'_ comes from _'kip-house'_ (and ultimately from the Danish _'Kippe'_ meaning hovel). One might as well say that _'doss'_ comes from _'doss-house'_ (... it doesn't).  There are at least three candidates for the origin of the expression and all are in English or Scots dialect.

Comment: Possibly related --there is a term ["kip up"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kip-up) meaning to jump from lying down to a standing position by kicking the legs strongly.  I've always associated it with Chinese martial arts, but I'm not aware of the origin of the word.  If it isn't related, the etymology of it might be an interesting other question.

Comment: I know the answer, but I'm afraid I will have to kip it to myself.

Comment: @Drew *groan* *groan* *groan* *groan* *groan* *groan* (I'll kip on doing it, until someone tells me to stop) :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Groan ahead. We'll see just how long you can kip it up.

Comment: @ChrisSunami.  A good find.  One of the interesting things about _'kip'_ is that it is often used in combination with _'..down'_ (as is _'bed..'_ and _'lie..'_).  Which suggests that _'kip'_ originally referred to either a bed (or bedding roll (of hides?)) or a body position (as in the case of _'doss'_ ).   _'Kip up'_ is used in gymnastics as well as martial arts, and although it may have a Asiatic origin, I suspect an English/Scots/Dutch/Afrikaans (yes it's a wide net...) origin perhaps involving _'kop'_ (head), although in Czech _'kip'_ (apparently) means _'kick'_.  A deep rabbit hole...

Answer (score 3):

Could the BE slang term ‘kip’ meaning to sleep be a borrowing from Hokkien?  I searched Hobson/Jobson and came up with this:

> CHOP-CHOP . Pigeon-English (or -Chinese) for 'Make haste! look sharp!' This is supposed to be from the Cantonese, pron. kăp-kăp, of what is in the Mandarin dialect **kip-kip.** In the Northern dialects kwai-kwai, 'quick-quick' is more usual (Bishop Moule). [Mr. Skeat compares the Malay chepat-chepat, 'quick-quick.']

The characters here, as Janus suggested, are most likely 急急.  Hobson-Jobson is clearly mistaken in referring to ‘kip-kip’ as Mandarin rather than Hokkien.  This entry might be read as saying that ‘chop-chop’ and ‘kip-kip’ were competing forms donated by different Chinese dialects/languages.  However, it’s not clear if the latter was ever used in English or not.

In any case, if English had already borrowed a version of this Chinese word to mean ‘quick’ with no semantic shift, why would it re-borrow the same word from a different dialect to mean ‘sleep’?  It seems highly unlikely.  Generally, to establish a relationship of borrowing we would want to have three things:  (A) a phonetic link,  (B) a semantic link and (C) a context (a time and place where the donor and recipient languages would have been in contact.)

With ‘kip’ we have A, it seems, but even that could be challenged.  Initial ‘k’ represents an aspirated stop in both English and pinyin, but in other Chinese dialects it might well be pronounced without aspiration and thus sound more like an English ‘g’.  And how did Cantonese ‘gap’ become English ‘chop’?  Sound change in borrowed words can be idiosyncratic.

Concerning B, any semantic link between ‘quick’ and ‘sleep’ would be forced.  Did Chinese people in a 19th century treaty port who wanted to take a nap after lunch ever say ‘kip-kip’ to signify ‘just a short one’ to English people, who then misinterpreted the word to mean sleep?  It seems too tenuous to take seriously.

Finally C, the context.  Where would the hypothetical encounter in B have taken place, and at what point in time?  The history of Chinese-Western contact is of course very complex.  We might be talking about the south China coast in the 19th century.  The main treaty ports frequented by English traders, at least before the country was ‘opened up’ after the 1840 Opium War, were Canton and Hong Kong.  Since these are located in a Cantonese-speaking area, it’s probably safe to take Cantonese as the default donor language for loans into British English.  However, other points of contact like Singapore would have had a different mix of dialect groups – generally for Southeast Asia the Hokkien communities were larger and more numerous than Cantonese ones, so the contact language might have been Hokkien.  And so on.

The formal title of Hobson/Jobson is ‘Glossary of Anglo-Indian Words and Phrases…’, but it actually covers ‘Oriental terms’ more broadly, not just South Asian ones.  More about this dictionary here:

[Hobson-Jobson definitively](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/06/25/hobson-jobson-definitively/)

TL/DR:  No, ‘kip’ wasn’t borrowed from Chinese.

Comment: +1 for taking my question seriously and doing some thorough research but like TimLymington I think you've interpreted my question in the wrong light. I am not suggesting that *kip* was borrowed to mean *quick/short sleep* but rather *kip* was used as an adjective in front of the word *sleep* or *nap*. Might it not have started out as *kip-sleep* or *kip-nap* and then over time became clipped as *kip*? A foreign traveller might have asked for a *kip meal* (with the word *meal* said in Hokkein) to mean  either a snack or just a plain bowl of rice or soup, i.e. a "quick meal".

Comment: The trouble is, 急 is not really a neutral word for something fast or short in duration.  Most of its uses in compounds involve suddenness, urgency, anxiety or nervousness.  @Janus gave the example zhaoji ‘nervous’, which is probably the most common use.  And this isn’t only in Mandarin - a Cantonese online dictionary I checked showed that it often appears in compounds meaning ‘emergency’ as in room or exit.

Comment: I’ve never seen it in combination with sleep or nap – wouldn’t a nervous, sudden or urgent nap would be a kind of oxymoron, barring some rare sleep disorder?  The usual term for ‘siesta’ in Chinese includes the time of day – an afternoon nap.  By the way, I hope my tone isn’t too severe here – it’s a fun question!

Comment: Ahh... OK. I was tempted to think that *kip* had a sort of generic "haste/quick" meaning, which could have been loaned to for example to say a five-minute nap. Perhaps not, if the connotations are more of a nervous anxious kind. Interesting to hear about its use for emergency and exit rooms. Oh well, lets see if anyone is inspired by your answer to reply.

Comment: hi from liguria mari-lou - I too have never-ever seen it used in English in combination with sleep or nap.  you just use it, alone, to mean "nap"

Comment: PS it strikes me as a military slang - has anyone looked in to that?

Answer (score 3):

I could not find evidence that the term *kip* has Chinese origins. The Danish word *kippe* appears to be the only documented origin so far.

According to  [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-kip1.htm): the term probably comes from the Danish term ***kippe*** that means hut, also used to refer to a mean alehouse. First  used  as an Irish slang term meaning brothel it was later used to refer to a place where one sleeps and then  as noun and verb that refer to taking a nap:

> - ***The ultimate source is probably the Danish word kippe for a hut or a mean alehouse.*** It was first recorded in the middle of the eighteenth century as an Irish slang term for a brothel. The earliest example known is from Oliver Goldsmith’s The Vicar of Wakefield.
> - ***As Goldsmith was Irish, educated in Dublin, the implication is that the word was first used in that city. It has long continued to be used there in that way, and appears in compound form in James Joyce’s Ulysses of 1922: “I saw him, kipkeeper!”.***  That word is remembered in a 1994 book with the title Dublin Tenement Life: “Now we didn’t call them ‘madams’, the outsiders called them madams. We called them ‘kip-keepers’.
> - By the latter part of the nineteenth century in Britain (as opposed to Ireland) the word had gone further down in the world to mean a common lodging-house for tramps and the homeless.
> - ***Soon after it transferred in sense from the place where you sleep to the act of sleeping itself (though in Scotland the word can mean a bed)***. In the twentieth century it shifted still further away from slang towards the modern informal or colloquial usage.

From the OED:

Early meaning and usages of the term ***Kip***:

(Also 6. *kyppe*, *keippe*, *kepe*, 7. *kipp(e)*

> - [***Of uncertain origin***. Sense 2 corresponds to MDu. *kip*, *kijp*, pack or bundle, esp. of hides (see Verwijs and Verdam); but there is no direct evidence that sense 1 was developed from 2.
>     Hardly to be connected with Flem. *kippe* new-born or young calf, G. *kippe* ewe.]
> - ***1.*** The hide of a young or small beast (as a calf or lamb, or cattle of small breed), as used for leather.
>
>   - ***1530*** Palsgr. 236/1 Kyppe of lambe a furre [no Fr.].
>   - ***1617*** *Nottingham Rec.* IV. 353 A kipp to make a cover for the charter.
> - ***2*** A set or bundle of such hides, containing a definite number: see quots.
>
>   - ***1525*** *Northumbld. Househ. Bk*. (1827) 355, ij Keippe and a half [of lamb skin] after xxx Skynnes in a Kepe.
>   - ***1612*** A. Hopton *Concord. Yeares* 164 The skins of Goats are numbered by the Kippe, which is 50.

***Kip***: early usages  both as a verb and as a noun that refer to nap/sleep:

> - A common lodging-house; also a lodging or bed in such a house; ***hence, a bed in general; a sleep, the action of sleeping.*** Also (rare) *kipp*, and Comb. as *kip-house*, *kip-shop*.
>
>   - ***1879*** *Macm. Mag.* XL. 501/1 So I went home, turned into kip (bed).
>   - ***1883*** *Pall Mall G.* 27 Sept. 4/1 The next alternative is the common lodging-house, or ‘kip’, which, for the moderate sum of fourpence, supplies the applicant with a bed.
> - **(*intr*.)**  ***To go to bed, sleep.***  Also, to lie down. So ‘**kipping**’ *vbl*. *n.*; also *attrib.*, as **kipping-house**, a lodging-house.
>
>   - ***1889*** Barrère & Leland *Dict. Slang I*. 522/1 *Kip*, to (popular and thieves), to sleep or lodge.
>   - ***1899*** C. Rook *Hooligan Nights* i. 10  Next door..that's where me and my muvver kipped when I was a nipper.

(OED)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I reduced the bold in the OED's citations, I think it's more legible now. And by the way, you did an excellent job of picking the most relevant quotations. Bravo!

Answer (score 3):

Some extra info on the Dutch connection that might be useful:

- In [Bruges dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruges_dialect), *kip* [also means bed](http://www.vlaamswoordenboek.be/definities/toon/1022)!
- In Standard Dutch, *kip* [means chicken](http://www.vandale.be/opzoeken?pattern=kip&lang=ne). (This seems unrelated, but perhaps it's worth bringing up.)

The page from *het Vlaams woordenboek* doesn't provide any etymology for *kip* in the sense of *bed*, so it might as well have arrived into Bruges dialect through British influence.

Answer (score 3):

In [*A Dictionary of Slang, Jargon & Cant Embracing English, American, and Anglo-Indian Slang, Pidgin English, Gypsies' Jargon and Other Irregular Phraseology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=et7WAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA492&dq=%22tatter%20a%20kip%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqgfvc8_PJAhUJ2mMKHaOEDR0Q6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22tatter%20a%20kip%22&f=false), Volume 1 (Albert Barrère, Charles Godfrey Leland, G. Bell, 1897), another story of the origin of 'kip' is presented as *probable*. Barrère, Leland and Bell (hereafter BLB) got at least one thing at least partially wrong, but what they got wrong can be corrected with modern sources (the etymology of 'kipe' as shown in the *OED Online*).

[image]

By this account, 'kip', meaning 'a bed', comes from 'kipsy', meaning 'a basket'. BLB remark, without making any necessary connection, that French thieves use a corruption of the French word meaning 'basket' to refer to 'a bed'.

BLB then define and explore the putative origins of 'kipsy':

[image]

Here BLB suggest 'kipsy', meaning 'a basket', might derive from Old English or Norman English *quipsure*. In that case, 'kipe', meaning 'a basket' is an abbreviation of 'kipsy'. However, and as it happens more in line with BLB's second thoughts on the derivation of 'kipe', *OED Online* provides a thorough etymology of 'kipe' in the sense of 'a basket', along with quotations attesting to that sense and going back to around 1000:

> **kipe**, *n.*
>   **Etymology**:  Old English *cýpe* weak feminine, apparently = Low German *küpe* (*keupe*) basket carried in the hand or on the back. Low German has also *kîpe*, *kiepe* (recorded from 15th cent., also spelt *kype*, *kypp*); whence modern German *kiepe*, Dutch *kiepe* (*korf*). The relationship of the forms is obscure, as is that between Low German *küpe* basket and *kûpe* tub, cask, and that of Old English *cýpe* to Middle English *cūpe* ....
>   Now *dial.*
>   A basket; †spec. an osier basket used for catching fish (obs.); a basket used as a measure (dial.).
>   c1000   *West Saxon Gospels*: Luke (Corpus Cambr.) ix. 17   Man nam þa gebrotu þe þar belifon, twelf cypan fulle.

This origin of 'kip', as elucidated by BLB and corroborated in part by the *OED Online* etymological history of 'kipe', doesn't involve the [Hok-keen dialect senses of 'kip'](https://books.google.com/books?id=rNFIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA713&dq=%22kip%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_tO-B7vPJAhVB7WMKHYHZAHw4mAcQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22kip%22&f=false), nor does it involve a putative Dutch etymon.

The account does explain the development of the contemporary verbal and nominal 'sleep, nap' senses of 'kip' from 'kip' in the senses of 'a bed' and 'to sleep, lodge' in thieves' and popular slang of the 1800s. 'Kip' is supposed ("probably") to be a shortening of 'kipsy' in the sense of 'a basket', and the parallel development of French thieves slang for 'a bed' from "a corruption" of the French word for 'a basket' is noted. Correlated with the form 'kipe', then, 'kipsy' and its abbreviation 'kip' is shown by the *OED Online* etymology to be derived from Old English *cýpe*, also meaning 'a basket', attested from c1000.

Answer (score 2):

The OED thinks the 'sleep/bed' sense comes from 'house of ill-fame', for which there is a 1766 citation (from the *Vicar of Wakefield*, of all places). There certainly was trade contact with China at that stage, both British and Dutch; but not among the urban masses who later used the word to mean 'sleep'. In addition, I don't really see how any of the Amoy meanings could transfer to `sleep'; I would think this is just another of the coincidences that English etymology is full of.

Comment: No, not sleep but a **quick** *sleep*, perhaps? There are so many words in Amoy with *kip* attached, I'm sure it would have been one of the first words merchants would have become familiarised with, don't you think? It's easy to pronounce, and it lends the idea of something fast, not lasting.

Comment: It’s general practice in south China and Taiwan to take a siesta or afternoon nap. It might well have been a cultural sticking point in Chinese/Western interaction on the south China coast under colonial conditions. It wouldn’t be surprising then if the English adopted a native word to designate the practice, just as we call it a ‘siesta’.